# find the jar that contains a given java class

Tags: java, hyperion

I am trying to find which .jar detected this error so I can figure out the issue. This is running on hyperion server.

```
[2015-03-15T15:18:35.352+08:00] [Planning0] [WARNING] [] [oracle.EPMHSP.calcmgr_execution] [tid: 144] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 00iRyJJB65hDOd5LzQL6iW000ly40016YL,0:1] [APP: PLANNING#11.1.2.0] [URI: /HyperionPlanning/faces/RunTimePromptTF/BgImage] [SRC_CLASS: com.hyperion.planning.adf.artifact.datacontrol.HspManageArtifactsDC] [SRC_METHOD: executeCalcScript] Error detected while attempting to run job Test_Rule [[
com.hyperion.planning.HspRuntimeException: Error detected while attempting to run job: Test_Rule.
  at com.hyperion.planning.HspAsyncJobsManager.completeJobExceution(HspAsyncJobsManager.java:101)
  at com.hyperion.planning.db.HspFMDBImpl$CalcMgrWrapper.runRule(HspFMDBImpl.java:10411)
  at com.hyperion.planning.db.HspFMDBImpl.runHBRRule(HspFMDBImpl.java:2254)
  at com.hyperion.planning.db.HspFMDBImpl.runCalcScript(HspFMDBImpl.java:2218)
  at com.hyperion.planning.HyperionPlanningBean.runCalcScript(HyperionPlanningBean.java:4028)
  at com.hyperion.planning.adf.artifact.datacontrol.HspManageArtifactsDC.executeCalcScript(HspManageArtifactsDC.java:3518)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.invokeMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:677)
  at oracle.adf.model.bean.DCBeanDataControl.invokeMethod(DCBeanDataControl.java:445)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running linux/unix flavor, I usually find jars via something like the following bash script:

```
for i in $( find LIB_FOLDERS -iname *.jar | xargs ); do 
    ( zipinfo $i | grep -i PATTERN ) && echo $i ; done
```

Where `LIB_FOLDERS` is the place where your jars are found, and `PATTERN` is a characteristic part of the name of the class you are looking for. This will print the names of all jar-files that match the pattern. Most IDEs allow you to "search for a class in the classpath" withouth all that command-line hassle, but I don't know if you have all sources loaded up in one.

Answer (score 0):

On linux systems I create ~/bin/findjar with the following, then chmod 700 and add ~/bin to my PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: findjar <classname or string to search for> [path to search under]
#
class=$1
path=$2

if [[ "$path" = "" ]]; then
  path=.
fi
echo searching for $class in $path
for f in `find $path -name "*.jar"`; do
  match=$(jar tf $f | grep $class);
  if [[ -n "$match" ]]; then
    echo
    echo $f;
    echo "$match"
  fi;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JarScan.  It's one of my favorite tools to search for a class buried in some jar in some directory. Works for any platform, simple and easy to use: https://java.net/projects/jarscan/pages/Tutorial/text